# React Native RefreshControl iOS release to refresh

Tags: react-native, uirefreshcontrol

I want to implement release to refresh with [RefreshControl](https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol), in iOS, when swipe down, the `onRelease` auto trigger, I want to trigger when it's released. Can someone give me some advices? Thanks in advance.